# php is shifting my images

Tags: php, image, css, alignment

http://jajuka.net/stark/logo.php

Iv generated image buttons with php but for some reason the images appear shifted to the right. Iv tried fixing it with CSS but that didn't seem to help. Here is the code iv used as well as the css and a live example. please someone help me.

```
<?php

    $dirname = "artwork/logo/";

    $images = scandir($dirname);

    shuffle($images);

    $ignore = array(".", "..");

    foreach($images as $curimg){

        if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
            echo "<div id='button'> <dir id='button_inside'> <img src='".$dirname.$curimg."'> </img> </dir> </dir>";

        }

    }              

?>
```

//--------------------------{ CSS }-----------------------//

```
#button {
border: 1px solid #999;
border-radius: 15px;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
height: 57px;
width: 57px;
float: left;
background-color: #FFF;
}
#button_inside {
float: left;
border-radius: 14px;
height: 55px;
width: 55px;
margin-top: 1px;
margin-right: 1px;
margin-bottom: 1px;
margin-left: 1px;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
background: rgb(242,242,242); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,242,242,1) 7%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 21%, rgba(226,226,226,1) 77%, rgba(226,226,226,1) 86%, rgba(254,254,254,1) 94%, rgba(211,211,211,1) 98%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(7%,rgba(242,242,242,1)), color-stop(21%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(77%,rgba(226,226,226,1)), color-stop(86%,rgba(226,226,226,1)), color-stop(94%,rgba(254,254,254,1)), color-stop(98%,rgba(211,211,211,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,242,242,1) 7%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 21%,rgba(226,226,226,1) 77%,rgba(226,226,226,1) 86%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 94%,rgba(211,211,211,1) 98%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,242,242,1) 7%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 21%,rgba(226,226,226,1) 77%,rgba(226,226,226,1) 86%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 94%,rgba(211,211,211,1) 98%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,242,242,1) 7%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 21%,rgba(226,226,226,1) 77%,rgba(226,226,226,1) 86%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 94%,rgba(211,211,211,1) 98%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(242,242,242,1) 7%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 21%,rgba(226,226,226,1) 77%,rgba(226,226,226,1) 86%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 94%,rgba(211,211,211,1) 98%); /* W3C */

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f2f2f2', endColorstr='#d3d3d3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}



img {
float: left;
height: 40px;
width: 40px;

overflow: visible;

}
```

Comment: This seems more like a question for [so].

Comment: This is a client-side issue that has nothing to do with PHP. Show your HTML, not your PHP.

Comment: There seems to a left padding of 40px's on `<div id="button_inside">`, set `style="padding:0px"` to see for yourself. For future uses, use a tool like Firebug to debug anything related to Javascript, HTML and CSS.

Comment: yea, only 1 element on a page can have the same id.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably got a type-o there....

```
<div...><dir...>...</dir></dir>
```

div/dir mixing you've got going?

Answer (score 1):

Not really a php question as the PHP simply outputs the HTML.

One issue is that you have multiple elements with the same ID. Change it to a `class` instead.

Example: `id="button"` should be `class="button"`.

Also change your CSS so it matches the class instead of an ID:

`#button {` should be `.button {`

Another is that some of your elements are `dir` instead of `div`.

I pulled it up on Chrome's dev tools and it shows `#button_inside` has a left padding of 40px. I don't see it defined anywhere, but setting a style `padding: 0` on it seems to put the element in place. Still, fix the issues with the code first before doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with you `<dir>` tags. Once I changed them to `<div>` they seemed to fall in line.

Also, `<dir>` is a deprecated tag as of HTMl 4.01 and removed from HTML 5 so you really don't want to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
<?php
foreach(glob("artwork/logo/*") as $f) {
    echo <<<HTML
        <div class="button" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;
             background-image: url('$f');">
        </div>
HTML;
}
```

Note that the location of the 'HTML;' is significant, see the [php documentation on heredoc strings](http://php.net/heredoc).

Comment: Alternatively, you could just wrap each part of the php code in `<?php ?>` and leave HTML as-is.